# Deriving the SQL query from sys.syslockinfo

Tags: sql-server

With the following query I can find processes on the dataserver

```
select *,db_name(rsc_dbid) as db_name from sys.syslockinfo (nolock)
```

Can I derive the SQL query from processes that are blocked?

Specifically, we get orphaned, blocking processes (with a req_spid of -2) but we don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [sp_WhoIsActive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx) from Adam Machanic. It tells you what's running, what's blocking, and it derives the SQL text from those queries.

Comment: That, sir, is awesome.